# Rails - has_one :through and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to design a club system. A club has many users, a user has one club, and a membership to store some info.
Can I use has_one :through and has_many :through to build one-to-many associations?

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users， through: :memberships
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :club, through: :membership
  has_one :membership
end
```

Because in the Rails Guides, it mentions has_one :through to build one-to-one association, and has_many :through to build many-to-many association.
Can I use this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. You have to adjust your models a bit to define your `through` part before defining another association that goes through it, i.e.

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users， through: :memberships
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :membership
  has_one :club, through: :membership
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!   I've been puzzled for a long time. :)